# How long someone can stay awake?

Tags: sleep

I cant escape sleeping a single night, though I tried. But 2 of my friends claimed that they did stay awake around 30 days nonstop! Nothing would be more difficult to believing than this to me!

I find it hard to believe but their face looked like they were telling the truth.

And another said he sleeps around 2 hours daily.

Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps if the [frontal lobe is damaged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Kern).

Comment: @CountIblis, I am looking for more detail about this story! I didn't know that. 40 years is unbelievable! Were he able to work and act like a normal people after that?   :O

Comment: Hey, just saw the symptoms here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontal_lobe_disorder    but these friends of mine have normal behavior/ activities like us. They are also doing well in their profession.. :S

Comment: @CountIblis Even if the person suffered severe frontal lobe damage they still could not survive without sleep for that long; primarily because the essential bodily nutrients formed during sleep would not be  provided to the person due to their lack of rest.

Comment: Some students struggle to stay awake for 30 minutes straight...

Comment: @RobSterach There may still be the one in a ten billion exception. Only  a few cases like Paul Kern have ever been reported, while the total number of people who have lived on Earth since the modern mass media would likely have picked up cases like that is of the order of 20 billion or so. This means that you have to be very sure about there not being some extremely rare, one in a ten billion chance loophole allowing for this to happen.

Comment: If so, then some people like me wonder how to have that exception.. Sigh, I never can sleep less than 8 hours. How poor. :'(

Answer (score 1):

There are two different answers to your question. For the friends that are saying they stayed awake for 30 days without a break for sleep, these friends are obviously pulling your leg. To make things more clear, IT IS IMPOSSIBLE TO STAY AWAKE FOR 30 DAYS STRAIGHT WITHOUT DYING, so if your friends are presumably "alive," then they were lying. I should also note that the World Record for most days without sleep tolls to be about 11. If somebody went past 2 or 3 weeks without sleeping, they would die. Common side effects of lack of sleep persisting more than a single day can be hallucinations, confusion, blurred vision, immune system shutting down(I don't believe it is for good, though, as with the other things), slurred speech, in other words, the person who was lacking proper sleep would experience close symptoms to that of a person who was drunk. Secondly, the friend who says he sleeps about 2 hours daily could in theory be doing this, but he would eventually die of a heart attack after about 10 years of this so I advise you suggest to him that he add about 5-7 extra hours of sleep onto his current level so he totals with about 7-9 hours daily. If your friend is sleeping 2 hours daily though, he probably would currently be a very crabby person and also show symptoms of exhaustion and confusion constantly, assuming he has been doing this for over 4 or 5 days. He would also have black or purple rings under his eyes.

Comment: I also can't believe. Btw,  did you see this story? just got it from the above comment! :O   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Kern

Comment: @NadiaAli 40 years without sleep? Impossible. This link had obviously been tampered by a troll on Wikipedia.